# Creating correct date format for SELECT...BETWEEN query

Tags: php, mysql, date, select

I have 2 variables which make up a date range which then needs to be searched in a MySQL database.

These are in the format 'Apr, 2011' and 'Mar, 2012' etc.

My SELECT...BETWEEN query requires '2011-04-01' and '2012-03-31', so whats the best way to provide this...

Convert the dates in PHP first?

Or is there a way to write the query to search using the original format?  I tried with date_format (date, '%b, %Y') but the query found nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename 
WHERE dateCol BETWEEN DATE_ADD(DATE(STR_TO_DATE('Apr, 2011', '%b, %Y')), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND LAST_DAY(STR_TO_DATE('Mar, 2012', '%b, %Y'));
```

Check the [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cc200/1)

Comment: Hi. Your query works but doesnt it assume that the month ends on the 31st?  What happens when this is not the case, will it cause a problem?

Comment: @highfidelity Check my updated answer it will find last day of the month

Comment: UPDATE: Actually the query does NOT find records with a date of the LAST day of the month ie 31 Mar 2012 - any ideas?

Comment: What is the problem? Explain it with sqlfiddle demo because as per me it should work

Comment: I have checked from my side, it's working. And if it won't work for you than explain me the scenario of that.

Comment: @highfidelity Have you checked the SQL FIDDLE DEMO It will give you the output as you want. If you find any issue then explain with SQL FIDDLE DEMO.